# In SQL Server, how to concat --> group by using the concat column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT
    'dbo.our_table' as table_name,
    CONCAT(col1, '-', col2, '-', col3) as table_id,
    COUNT(*) as ct 
FROM dbo.our_table
group by table_name, table_id
-- group by 1, 2 -- this doesn't work either...
order by ct desc
```

This does not work in SQL server because it does not recognize table_name or table_id. I understand that this can be done by nesting a 2nd `SELECT` clause into the `FROM`, so that table_name and table_id are explicitly available, however I am trying to understand if it is possible to achieve this output without having to create a nested `SELECT` statement, but rather by keeping the structure of my current query but only making a tweak.

Thanks

Comment: Can't group by an alias.  Simply try Group By CONCAT(col1, '-', col2, '-', col3)   No need for table_name because it is a constant

Comment: Or you could `GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3`, as those are the columns in your expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to specify the full calculation for the `GROUP BY` as well as for the `SELECT`. This is because `GROUP BY` is logically considered before `SELECT`, so cannot access those calculations.**

You could do it like this (`table_name` is not necessary because it's purely computed):

```sql
SELECT
    'dbo.our_table' as table_name,
    CONCAT(col1, '-', col2, '-', col3) as table_id,
    COUNT(*) as ct 
FROM dbo.our_table
group by CONCAT(col1, '-', col2, '-', col3)
order by ct desc;
```

**But much better is to place calculations in a `CROSS APPLY`, this means it is accessible later by name as you wished:**

```sql
SELECT
    'dbo.our_table' as table_name,
    v.table_id,
    COUNT(*) as ct 
FROM dbo.our_table
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CONCAT(col1, '-', col2, '-', col3) ) ) as v(table_id)
group by v.table_id
order by ct desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to put your 3 columns (`col1`, `col2` & `col3`) into the `GROUP BY`. Unlike these 3 columns, `dbo.our_table` is not needed in the `GROUP BY` as it is a string.

SQL Server executes the components of `SELECT` queries in a particular order starting with `FROM`, then `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, etc. In this case, SQL Server doesn't recognize the aliases `table_name` & `table_id` in the `GROUP BY` because they are not set until the `SELECT`, which is executed after the `GROUP BY`.
Googling "SQL Server SELECT query execution order" should give you a number of resources which will explain the order of execution in more detail.